How do I get the modal dialog box to display customized with two different buttons?
So I am working on the TicTacToe game for the Odin Project. I have two different create Player buttons that I want to open the same modal dialog box so I can enter in two different parameters and have one save across both.When I put X as the marker for one player I want it to be (required?) inaccessible for the other player, so that the other player has to pick O.How do I do this?
HTML
<body>
    <header> TIC-TAC-TOE</header>
    <section id="large-container">
        <article class="Players" id="1">
            Player1
            <button id="1">
                Enter Player
            </button>
        </article>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="item"><button id="0">0</button></div>
            <div class="item"><button id ="1">1</button></div>
            <div class="item"><button id="2">2</button></div>
            <div class="item"><button id="3">3</button></div>
            <div class="item"><button id="4">4</button></div>
            <div class="item"><button id="5">5</button></div>
            <div class="item"><button id="6">6</button></div>
            <div class="item"><button id="7">7</button></div>
            <div class="item"><button id="8">8</button></div>
        </div>
        <article class="Players" id="2">
            Player2
            <button id="2">
                Enter Player
            </button>
        </article>
        <dialog class="PlayerDialog">
            <form>
                <p>
                    <label for="playerName">What is the Player's Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="PName" name="PName">

                    <label for="playerMarker">What is the Players marker?
                        <select>
                            <option value="X" id="X" name="Marker">X</option>
                            <option value="O" id="O" name="Marker">O</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </p>
                <button value="cancel" formmethod="dialog">Cancel</button>
                <button id="Confirm" value="default">Confirm</button>
            </form>
        </dialog>
    </section>
    <script src="Main3.js"></script>
</body>


JS
const playerCreationButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".Players > button")
const playerCreation = document.querySelector(".PlayerDialog")
const PlayerDisplay = document.querySelector("article.Players")
const confirmBtn = document.querySelector("#Confirm")
const playerName = document.getElementById("#PName")
const playerMarkerX = document.getElementById("X")
playerCreationButtons.forEach((button)=>{
    button.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
         /// (Some code here to alter the modal for each player before it's shown)///
        playerCreation.showModal()
        console.log(`${button.id}`)
    })
})



Editing old information, I was able to fix 1 of my problems but not the other. Thanks in advance.

In order for you to do that, you will need to setup up a backend, that will handle the users data, then you will connect to your front end and now you can check which player to show the modal 2, player A or B.

why not add id attributes to your select element and dialog for better control in JavaScript and you can handle the marker selection to ensure the second player can’t select the already chosen marker:
<body>
<header>TIC-TAC-TOE</header>
<section id="large-container">
    <article class="Players" id="1">
        Player 1
        <button id="player1Button">Enter Player</button>
    </article>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Tic-Tac-Toe grid -->
        <div class="item"><button id="0">0</button></div>
        <!-- More grid items -->
        <div class="item"><button id="8">8</button></div>
    </div>
    <article class="Players" id="2">
        Player 2
        <button id="player2Button">Enter Player</button>
    </article>
    <dialog id="PlayerDialog" class="PlayerDialog">
        <form id="playerForm">
            <p>
                <label for="PName">What is the Player's Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="PName" name="PName">
                <label for="playerMarker">What is the Player's marker?</label>
                <select id="playerMarker" name="Marker">
                    <option value="X" id="X" name="Marker">X</option>
                    <option value="O" id="O" name="Marker">O</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <button type="button" value="cancel" formmethod="dialog">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" id="Confirm" value="default">Confirm</button>
        </form>
    </dialog>
</section>
<script src="Main3.js"></script>

const playerCreationButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".Players > button");
const playerCreation = document.querySelector("#PlayerDialog");
const playerNameInput = document.querySelector("#PName");
const playerMarkerSelect = document.querySelector("#playerMarker");
const confirmBtn = document.querySelector("#Confirm");

let player1Marker = null;
let player2Marker = null;

playerCreationButtons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        // Reset form fields
        playerNameInput.value = "";
        playerMarkerSelect.value = "";

        // Determine which player is selecting
        if (button.id === "player1Button") {
            playerCreation.setAttribute("data-player", "1");
            if (player2Marker) {
                // If player 2 has already chosen, remove their option from player 1's select
                document.getElementById(player2Marker).disabled = true;
            d.   ocument.getElementById(player2Marker === "X" ? "O" : "X").disabled = false;
            } else {
            // If player 2 hasn't chosen, enable both options
            document.getElementById("X").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("O").disabled = false;
        }
    } else if (button.id === "player2Button") {
        playerCreation.setAttribute("data-player", "2");
        if (player1Marker) {
            // If player 1 has already chosen, remove their option from player 2's select
            document.getElementById(player1Marker).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById(player1Marker === "X" ? "O" : "X").disabled = false;
        } else {
            // If player 1 hasn't chosen, enable both options
            document.getElementById("X").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("O").disabled = false;
        }
    }

        playerCreation.showModal();
   });
});

confirmBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const selectedMarker = playerMarkerSelect.value;
    const playerName = playerNameInput.value;
    const player = playerCreation.getAttribute("data-player");

    if (player === "1") {
        player1Marker = selectedMarker;
    } else if (player === "2") {
        player2Marker = selectedMarker;
    }

    console.log(`Player ${player} Name: ${playerName}, Marker: ${selectedMarker}`);
    playerCreation.close();
});

